# C# send data from Application to Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi All:
working on an asp.net mvc3 app that has a requirement to send data to another app which saves data to SQL.

So far i have one of the apps up and running and works well:
Users login and do basic CRUD operations; this has been established using C# MVC3 framework and works well.

The issue:
data needs to be saved to another external database where the host doesn't allow direct access to the SQL server and data must pass through IIS/Web-App/Firewall/Proxy etc.

The question:
what is the best way to send data from one application to another and what protocol to use "HTTP? Webservice? VPN?....". 
The connection has to be secure in a way that the application receiving the data has to authenticate the application sending the data.

i know this sounds unnecessarily complex but the client is deadlock on this implementation.
also this has to be implemented in ASP.NET C#/VB.NET. any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Are the applications running on the same machine? If so, I have used MSMQ successfully for secure and guaranteed message delivery. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: not really, they sit on completely different servers and Intranets

Comment: I have not remotely accessed MSMQ, but it is possible and used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webservice would make the most sense - You can implement your own authentication system (As you know the same application is always going to call the web-service)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/myservice.aspx

You could look at developing the service following the RESTful pattern (Using MVC) [RESTful Web Services with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220845/restful-web-services-with-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 3):

Message queues (MSMQ) is definitely an option to consider.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of data, the rate you going to send it, the network(LAN or WAN) and many other factors.

Also do you need to encryption and authentication ?

I would use **WCF** to communicate, the binding should be selected accordingly to the requirments of your specific application.

Please provide more information.

Comment: data size is minimal and rate is also minimal, encryption is not required but preferred, authentication is required.

Comment: @Ziad J Some basic configuration for your need would be a WCF service with WSHttpBinding, transport encryption, and Userame/Password authentication.